# nginx reverse proxy upstream server using domain name (ex. www.test.com)

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, nginx-upstreams

I have a website hosted somewhere in some server. lets say the domain name is **https://www.test.com**

Now, I am working on setting up the **reverse proxy** for this website using the *upstream server* for this domain name and it is not working.

I don't want to try it with the IP Address.
I want to try it upstream server with the domain name.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you generally interested in proxy_passing to upstream https or google in special? For the second i recommend this: https://www.linuxbabe.com/nginx/set-nginx-reverse-proxy-google-com

Comment: Hi @araisch thank you for the reply. I have modified the question. Kindly suggest the possible answer.